# Gulp compile SASS into relative subfolder

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-watch

If I have a file inside of `components/root/sass/index.scss`, how do I compile it to `components/root/styles/index.css`? Simply put, I want to replace `sass` in the path with `styles`, i.e. if I had a file at `components/second/sass/file.scss`, it would compile to `components/second/styles/file.css`.

This is my current code in `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('components/**/sass/*.scss', {base: "./"})
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../styles/'));
})

gulp.task('default', function () {
  gulp.watch('components/**/sass/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename each path replacing the "/sass" bit and it's extension via "gulp-rename" module.

I would recommend having the path globbing in a variable, the watch as a independent task, and the default task with both the "sass" and "watch" tasks.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var rename = require("gulp-rename");

var componentsGlob = './components/**/sass/*.scss';

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src(componentsGlob)
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(rename (function(path) {
      path.dirname = path.dirname.replace('/sass', '/styles');
      path.extname = ".css";
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./components/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch(componentsGlob, ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's putting it in the file `styles/index.css/index.css`?

Comment: I just edited the solution to one using gulp-rename module as it seems fits better the "gulp way", could you try this one?

Comment: I tried out with "components/root/sass/index.scss" and gets "components/root/styles/index.css". If it doesn't work share the problematic example to try out different a different replacement.

Answer (score 0):

No need for gulp-rename :

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('components/**/sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('components/root/styles'));
})
```

Basically, the 'components/root/styles' will replace everything before your src glob starts or, in your case, 'components'.

Comment: No, because if I had something inside of `components/abc/sass/`, then it wouldn't compile into `components/abc/styles/`.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I have edited my question to include clarity. Would you mind updating your answer as well, just to ensure the quality of this question?